# Data source for copied worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to copy three sheets (two sheets are pivot tables, one is the source data for those pivots) from one workbook to a new workbook.

The code below copies the desired sheets to the new workbook and saves it (modified [original](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=359)):

```
Sub ExportFile()
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        On Error GoTo ErrCatcher

        ' Array of sheets to copy
        Sheets(Array("sourcedata", "pivot", "pivot2")).Copy
        On Error GoTo 0

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Cells.Copy
            ' Paste sheets
            ws.[A1].PasteSpecial

            ' Remove external links, hyperlinks and hard-code formulas
            ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            ' Select A1 on sheet
            Cells(1, 1).Select
            ws.Activate
        Next ws
        Cells(1, 1).Select

        ' Save it in the same directory as original and close
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\export.xls"
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    Exit Sub

ErrCatcher:
    MsgBox "Specified sheets do not exist within this workbook"
End Sub
```

However, when I open the new workbook, the data source in the pivot tables still point to the original workbook. My colleague explained that this is because the sheets are being copied one by one, rather in a group and suggested to copy the sheets as a range. How would I go about copying the sheets as a range or would it be easier way to change the data source to the new copied sheets?

Comment: You'll need to change the source data of the Pivot Tables to the new workbook. Just because you copy all the sheets at once doesn't let the pivot table know that you want to change the source to the copied sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I felt that the easiest option was to just change the data source on the pivots. Not sure if this is the cleanest syntax or if there is a shortcut, but it works for me.

```
' Change pivot table data source
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="stagePivotData", _
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10)
```

Comment: @NJK, your answer includes info you didn't include in the original question -- nowhere in the question do you mention a range called "stagePivotData" in either workbook.

Comment: @ExactaBox That is my fault. At the time it may have seemed as though pointing to the sheet or a range was the same thing to me. Could you elaborate on how this may be advantageous?

Comment: End result: no advantage either way.  Just that the answer (the range name) was in your back pocket, so none of the responders could have provided the answer you ultimately deemed most appropriate.

Comment: @ExactaBox Sorry, I should have been explicit that the source data for the pivots was in the `sourcedata` worksheet. I did upvote your answer, however.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the creating a new workbook part by copying the entire worksheets, rather than the cells.

As far as pointing the new pivots to the new source, all you need to do is remove the external reference from the PivotSource.  It's in the format `[oldworkbook]sourcedata!A1:Z100` so you just need to truncate the part within the brackets.  (This isn't a universal solution, but in this case we're copying the data source tab and the pivot tabs simultaneously, so we know the new workbook will have a data tab with the same name, same size, same range, etc as the original workbook)

```
Sub CopyPivotsAndData()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable
Dim s As String
Dim r As Integer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.Worksheets(Array("sourcedata", "pivot", "pivot2")).Copy
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook

    Set ws = wbNew.Worksheets("pivot")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
    s = pt.SourceData
    r = InStr(s, "]")
    pt.SourceData = Mid(s, r + 1)

    'repeat for pivot2, or loop if you have many worksheets

    wbNew.SaveAs "newworkbookname.xlsx"

    'close or clean up as necessary

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to "move"(the worksheet equivalent of cut) the worksheets instead of just copying them. Copying anything in excel doesn't change any references to the new location of the copied data(it still uses the original data). But cutting data from one place to another will change any references to the new location of that data. So I would do something like this:

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Move Before:=Workbooks("Book2").Sheets(2)
```

This was recorded - obviously you would want to use the .Move command appropriately for your specific situation.

Or if you are doing this for cells you would want to use:

```
ws.Cells.Cut
```

It looks like you are closing the original workbook without saving at `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` so i don't think this is an issue - but just as an FYI: cutting won't affect your original copy unless you save it aftwerwards.

Comment: But if you move the sheets, then they are no longer in your original workbook, which would defeat the purpose of an `export` like feature.

Comment: It looks like he is closing the original workbook without saving anyways at ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False - But in any case as long as he doesn't save the orginal workbook after cutting from it - it won't affect the orginal workbook data. He can always save before the macro and then reopen it and return to save state.

Comment: Then this may be the way to go then, @njk